# how can I take user table data in a variable using CakePHP Auth

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I want take user table data in a variable using CakePHP Auth.

This is my code:

```
    $result = $this->Auth->User(['name']['email']);
    pr($result);
    exit;
```

How I will take data in variable?

Comment: Please add detail to your question. The verb **take** does not make sense in this context.

Comment: You can get the Auth user data with `$result = $this->Auth->User();` and then use `$result['name']` and `$result['email']` to get user Name and email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explore all elements first:

```
 $result = $this->Auth->User();
    pr($result);
    exit;
```

Now you can collect which data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise ,you can read it from session.

Do like this

```
$userDetails = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
debug($userDetails);
```

P/S: Always state your CakePHP version for better answer received.